# Does StackOverflow.com have a counter or graph of "unique IPs of visitors"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, statistics, web

Where can one find "unique visitors" counters for the last day/hour/month?

I guess I'm just curious about how much Stack Overflow has advanced since the "[Overnight Success](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001207.html)" article on Coding Horror.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this graph.](http://siteanalytics.compete.com/stackoverflow.com+experts-exchange.com/)

Comment: Excellent - just what I was looking for!

Comment: I'll be glad when the EE dinosaur finally goes down (or at least isn't widely used anymore)